# Sum of attributes after truncating a character from the value

Tags: xslt, attributes, sum

I have the following xml.

```
<xml>
  <table>
    <cols width="1.00*" />
    <cols width="2.00*" />
    <cols width="4.00*" />
       <row><p>Hello</p></row>          
  </table>
  <p>
     Life is good.
  </p>      
</xml>
```

**Explaination:**
I need to read the column width from the above xml and display. But in some cases user specifies the width so less that the table columns overlap on each other.
Hence I thought to do this formula.
col1width=col1width/totalWidth*100;
This will give me the table width in % format so that the columns get distributed properly.
But I am not able to take a total count of all these attributes. My xslt just does not work. Please see the xslt below:

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:template match="node()" mode="table">
    <fo:table table-layout="fixed">
              <fo:table-header>
          <fo:table-row>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current()/cols">
                       <xsl:variable name="maxWidth"
                select="number(substring-before(current()/table/cols/@width, '*')) + number(substring-before(following-sibling::cols/@width, '*'))" />
                    </xsl:for-each>
                  </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table>
```

**Solutions tried:**

1. I have tried using sum function. But here, before summing, i have to
   truncate the '*' character and convert to number and then add. Does
   not work.
2. Written a recursive template to get the sum. I am getting the sum with this. But I am not able to return the total width from the
   template. I guess xslt does not support returning of calculated
   values. Below is the recursive xslt.

   ```
      <xsl:template name="maximumTableWidth">
     <xsl:param name="total" select="0" />
     <xsl:param name="totalCols" />
     <xsl:param name="index" select="1" />
    <xsl:if test="$index &lt;= $totalCols">
      <xsl:variable name="maxWidth"
         select="$total + translate(current()/cols[$index]/@width, '*', '')" />   

               <xsl:call-template name="maximumTableWidth">
           <xsl:with-param name="total" select="$maxWidth" />
           <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$totalCols" />
           <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index + 1" />
       </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:if>
     </xsl:template>
   ```

XSLT call:

```
<xsl:template name="main">   
  <xsl:variable name="maximumWidth">                
            <xsl:call-template name="maximumTableWidth">
                <xsl:with-param name="total" select="0" />
                <xsl:with-param name="totalCols"
                    select="count(current()/cols)" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
 </xsl:template>
```

Here, the variable is of type string and hence has no value.
Please help me with this problem. Also can suggest any other approach for table column width. I am generating pdf output using xsl fo. And my whole xslt is dynamic. I cannot have a direct path like node1/node2/node3.

Thank you.

Comment: Please take care of your previous questions before asking new ones. To some of them correct answers have been given - **accept** those answers. For others, a clarification has been requested - **edit** those questions.

Comment: Could we see the required output on this one? Also, what's the asterisk next to the @width value? It doesn't look like the actual input - is it?

Comment: Please note that with XSLT 2.0, this problem becomes trivial. If you are constrained to use XSLT 1.0, please say so when raising questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a couple of problems with your **maximumTableWidth** template to start with. Firstly, you should probably wrap the `translate` function in the `number` function

```
<xsl:variable name="maxWidth"
              select="$total + number(translate(current()/cols[$index]/@width, '*', ''))" />
```

Secondly, you need to make sure you call it with the correct parameters. For your recursive call you set a parameter called **nodes**, when it should be **totalCols**

```
<xsl:with-param name="totalCols" select="$totalCols" />
```

But in terms of returning a value, all you need to do it use **xsl:value-of** to output the value, and your **maximumWidth** variable will then be set to that value. All you need to do is change the **xsl:if** in the template to an **xsl:choose** and output the value in the **xsl:otherwise** condition:

```
<xsl:template name="maximumTableWidth">
    <xsl:param name="total" select="0" />
    <xsl:param name="totalCols" />
    <xsl:param name="index" select="1" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$index &lt;= $totalCols">
            <xsl:variable name="maxWidth"
            select="$total + number(translate(current()/cols[$index]/@width, '*', ''))" />   
            <xsl:call-template name="maximumTableWidth">
                <xsl:with-param name="total" select="$maxWidth" />
                <xsl:with-param name="totalCols" select="$totalCols" />
                <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index + 1" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$total" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

There is another way to write this template recursively. Instead of passing in the index, and incrementing it, pass in the **cols** element itself, and use `following-sibling` to iterate over them. Try this template instead

```
<xsl:template name="maximumTableWidth">
    <xsl:param name="col" />
    <xsl:param name="total" select="0" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$col">
            <xsl:variable name="maxWidth"
            select="$total + number(translate($col/@width, '*', ''))" />   
            <xsl:call-template name="maximumTableWidth">
                <xsl:with-param name="total" select="$maxWidth" />
                <xsl:with-param name="col" select="$col/following-sibling::cols[1]" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$total" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

You would call this like so:

```
    <xsl:variable name="maximumWidth">                
            <xsl:call-template name="maximumTableWidth">
                <xsl:with-param name="col" select="cols[1]" />
            </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$maximumWidth" />
```

EDIT: If you were able to use XSLT 2.0, then you can do away with the named template altogether, and just set the **maximumWidth** template to this

```
<xsl:variable name="maximumWidth" select="sum(cols/(number(translate(@width, '*', ''))))" />
```

Comment: Hey Tim. Thank you so much. Your second solution using following-sibling just did the magic. I had tried using this, but I went wrong in few places. Thanks!!